# How many different ways are there for five lawyers and seven businessmen to sit around a circular table where no two lawyers are together?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**My attempt:**

[image]

So, let's say I place a lawyer at an arbitray position. Now, we know for sure that no lawyer can be placed adjacent to the one we just placed. Okay, good.

Now, how do I find the number of ways to arrange the remaining 4 lawyers? I'm lost. There are 9 remaining places, but I can't just do $^9P_4$ as that will not account for the fact that no two lawyers can be together. What can be done here?

**Edit:** Consider rotationally equivalent arrangements to be the same. However, do not consider reflected arrangements to be the the same.

Comment: I suggest:  Fix one (specified)  of the lawyers at the head of the table (that takes care of rotations).  Now consider the five gaps between the lawyers.  Use [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and then populate the lawyers and the businessmen with individuals.  Note:  I am assuming that rotationally equivalent arrangements are the same (though you never said that).  And I don't know if you want reflections to matter.

Comment: @lulu But there may be more than one gap between the lawyers. It isn't necessary that there will only be one gap between two lawyers.

Comment: @lulu Yes, rotationally equivalent arrangements are the same.

Comment: A gap is a gap.  It has as many seats as it has.  All we know is that it has at least one.  Since there are $5$ gaps and $7$ business people, we know that some gap has at least two seats.

Comment: Edit your post to clarify the problem.  It's usual in problems with circular tables to equate rotated arrangements.  Sometimes one also equates reflected arrangements, but not always.  That should be specified.

Comment: It may be easier to think of arranging the $7$ businesspeople, and then choosing $5$ of the $7$ gaps between the businesspeople in which to place the lawyers (there can, of course, be at most one lawyer in each gap).

Comment: @paw88789 Thank you. I'm a bit confused as to whether the answer will be $$7!\times^7P_5$$, or $$(7-1)!\times^7P_5$$ to account for the rotational equivalency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that one of the businessmen is Manuel.  Seat Manuel.  We will use him as our reference point.  Relative to Manuel, the remaining six businessmen can be seated in $6!$ ways as we proceed clockwise around the table.

Seating the businessmen creates seven spaces, one to the immediate left of each businessman, in which the lawyers can be placed.  To ensure that we separate the lawyers, we must select five of these seven spaces in which to seat a lawyer, which can be done in $\binom{7}{5}$ ways.  The lawyers can be arranged in the five selected spaces in $5!$ ways as we proceed clockwise around the table from Manuel.

Hence, there are
$$6!\binom{7}{5}5!$$
ways to seat seven businessmen and five lawyers at a round table so that no two of the lawyers sit in adjacent seats.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I think it is like this:

Fix one businessman's position, let's call him A. In front of him are the 5 lawyers. There are 6 gaps between them, including A. Let's call these gaps $x_1,x_2,...,x_6$, where $x_1$ is the gap closest to A's left, and $x_6$ to A's right. As the lawyers cannot sit next to each other, we are to place the remaining 6 businessmen into these gaps such that $x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ must have at least one businessman. Hence, we are to count the number of nonnegative integer solutions of $$x_1+x_2+...+x_6=6$$ such that $x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\geq 1$. With the transformations $y_i=x_i-1$ for each $i=2,3,4,5$, the equation becomes $$x_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+x_6=2,$$ where each variable is now required to just be nonnegative. There are 21 solutions to this.

However, we are not done. We have 21 possible placements, but each of these groups that A sees must be arranged, which give $5!=120$ ways for the lawyers, and $6!=720$ for the businessmen. Hence, there are $21*720*120=1814400$ ways.

Suggestion/correction is much welcomed!